# Value to hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, hex

I get my value like this

`var dataView= new DataView(imgData.array.buffer);
var st = dataView.getUint8(1).toString(10);`

Which gives me the value 216 decimal. How can I transform varibale st to (hex 0xD8).

When i have to 0xD8 how can I transform it to short and long!

Comment: Have you tried `.toString(16)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is the way to go:

```
var st = "0x" + dataView.getUint8(1).toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: That's it. Great! Thank you! Didn't saw that the 0x part is always the same!

Comment: How can I transform this value now to short and long??

Answer (score 3):

Use a different base in the [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) call:

```
var dataView= new DataView(imgData.array.buffer);
var st = dataView.getUint8(1).toString(16);
```

Comment: If I use 16 I only get d8 value and not 0xD8!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 16 instead of 10 as arguement to `toString()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp, see `radix` parameter